# Chrome Extension: Background page interval runs, but sees no jQuery plugin

Tags: google-chrome-extension, setinterval, google-chrome-storage

I am creating a chrome extension that has background, which runs every second and updates chrome.storage... and it is called `artistSetter.js`. Here it is:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(items){
    $.each($('#supplySong > a > span.sidebar-heading'), function(){
        if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(22, 156, 217)'){
            chrome.storage.local.set({"currentArtist": $(this)[0].innerText});
        }
    });
});
```

Background page is this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'js/artistSetter.js'});
}, 1000);
```

The error is this:

> Error in response to storage.get: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

The thing is that this is working after page refreshes. I understand, that this works because I `jQuery.js` starts running. But when I click `Reload` button, it stops working and I start getting the error every second. Again, after refreshing, it works. Because jQuery.js starts working.

How can I fix this? Really couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1):

Add the required plugin before running `artistSetter.js`, e.g.:

```
setInterval(function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'jquery.js'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'js/artistSetter.js'});
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Worked. Should've guessed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems like this option won't work, because other pages went truly crazy. Thanks anyway. The best option would probably be to change it from manifest, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the `setInterval` logic to content scripts, keep artistSetter.js only and remove background page?

Manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery.js",
        "artistSetter.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
```

artistSetter.js

```
setInterval(function () {
    chrome.storage.local.get(function(items){
        $.each($('#supplySong > a > span.sidebar-heading'), function(){
            if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(22, 156, 217)'){
                chrome.storage.local.set({"currentArtist": $(this)[0].innerText});
            }
        });
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Still doesn't recognize (

Answer (score 0):

As other solution, You can concatenate the two script files to one file with some tool (ex. [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)).