# Is it possible to have changing backgrounds on a timed interval?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome theme that changes backgrounds (every day). Is this possible? If so, how do I implement this in the JSON file?

Comment: AFAIK, this would be possible. You can use `setInterval`, as stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35591298/5995040), you can put the logic to content scripts at js perform the change background color. Hope this helps.